# Does Salesforce support IdP-initiated SAML when Salesforce is acting as the IdP?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I am trying to setup Salesforce Communities as a SAML IdP for our application following the procedures here: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Salesforce_IdP_Setup amongst other supporting documentation.

Our application currently expects the IdP (Salesforce) to initiate the SAML response to our application once the user has been redirected to Salesforce Login then completed Login. Does Salesforce support this?

Overall we are having trouble finding good documentation around setting up Salesforce as a SAML 2.0 IdP, most documentation focuses around having Salesforce as a Service Provider and setting up a separate application as a IdP. Is there any good documentation I am missing around this?

Comment: I struggled a lot with this myself when I setup Salesforce as an IdP for one of our third party websites, due to lack of documentation, but did finally manage to get it working so I can tell you that yes Salesforce does support it. The exact methods escape me right now but I just went to our third party site to test it, was redirected to Salesforce communities login, logged in, and was redirected back to (and signed in to) the third party site. I wish I could provide more specifics but we set it up nearly a year ago so I'd need to do some digging, but don't quit! It IS possible.

Comment: Nobody ever answered my question on stack, but here is a [link](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/98564/salesforce-as-idp-for-aha-io-single-sign-on-error-invalid-http-method) to my very similar question where I struggled with the same thing as you. In my question I mention that I downloaded the Metadata XML file from Salesforce Identity Provider Setup and uploaded it to the third party site (they had a place that let me upload the XML directly), from there, I remember I needed to tweak it a bit to fix the "Invalid HTTP Method" error but ultimately the answer is yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:

- Get an Identity Provider Certificate
- Supply the required information from your Salesforce configuration to the SP administrator
- On Salesforce, create a connected app to run the application in Salesforce
- Test the service provider–initiated SSO by entering the service provider–initiated login URL from the App Launcher

**References**

- [Get a Salesforce Identity Provider Certificate | Identity Implementation Guide | Salesforce Developers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.identityImplGuide.meta/identityImplGuide/identity_google_sfdc_id.htm)
- [Examples for Setting Up Identity Providers and Service Providers](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=identity_provider_examples.htm&type=5)