# Salesforce as IdP error - Invalid HTTP method

Tags: configuration, saml, identity-provider

I have built an application (Service Provider) and I want to use Salesforce as the SSO IdP using SAML 2.0.

When being redirected to Salesforce to authenticate the user, I get a 'Single Sign On Error: Invalid HTTP method' error and the page URL ends with 'SamlError?idpError=1505'
[image: Salesforce connected app config]

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Which endpoint are you redirecting the user to during the authentication? And have you got any logs at all that you could include? From [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/98564/salesforce-as-idp-for-aha-io-single-sign-on-error-invalid-http-method) question you might solve this by using the redirect not post endpoint.